# What's wrong with SetDelayed? The body of the function works alone, while setdelayed to it as $f[x\_]:=func$ gives the wrong answer

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction

So I was writing a function to get the poincare map of a given dynamic system, for example, the duffing oscillator.

I obtained the time series in advance, then take the poincare map based on this time series.

(*All the code is based on this [article](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.168743)*)

```
(*define the vector field*)
Duffing[f_, w_] := {v, -0.5*v - x^3 + x + f*Cos[z], w};

(*Obtain the orbits (numerical iteration)*)
OrbitFlow[flow_, vars_, x0_, {t0_, t1_}, opts___] := 
 Module[{rules, eq, l = Length[flow], tf, rhs}, 
  rules = Table[vars[[i]] -> vars[[i]][t], {i, 1, l}];
  rhs = flow /. rules;
  eq = Join[Table[D[vars[[i]] /. rules, t] == rhs[[i]], {i, 1, l}], 
    Table[vars[[i]][0] == x0[[i]], {i, 1, l}]];
  tf = Table[vars[[i]][t], {i, 1, l}];
  sol = NDSolve[eq, tf, {t, t0, t1}, opts]]
(*solving the equation*)

T=2 \[Pi]
sol = OrbitFlow[Duffing[0.39, 1], {x, v, z}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1000*T}];

(*to get the set by poincare map*)
poincare[timeseries_,w_]:=Module[{T=2\[Pi]/w,xsol,vsol},
xsol[t_]=x[t]/.timeseries;
vsol[t_]=v[t]/.timeseries;
((Join[xsol[#],vsol[#]]//Evaluate)&) /@Range[800*T,1000*T,T]
];
```

it doesn't evaluate, and returns:

```
In:= poincare[sol, 1] 
Out:= {{x[1600 \[Pi]], v[1600 \[Pi]]},...}
```

instead, if I run the code without function-defined 'poincare', it gives evaluated answers,

```
In:= Module[{T = 2 \[Pi]/1, xsol, vsol}, xsol[t_] = x[t] /. sol;
 vsol[t_] = v[t] /. sol;
 ((Join[xsol[#], vsol[#]] // Evaluate) &) /@ Range[800*T, 1000*T, T]]
Out:= {{-0.508376, 0.294264},...}
```

Though I know there are plenty of ways to do the same thing, I just wondered why this is wrong?

---

so it might be something wrong with my settings in NDSolve,
in my previous code, I used

```
NDSolve[eq,{x[t],v[t],z[t]},{~}]
```

so the output is a list of rules, like:

```
{{x[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[~],
  v[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[~],
  z[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[~],
}}
```

so that evaluation at a specific point may not work, although set another function may solve this but yet cause other problems,

```
In:= x[0.2]/.sol
Out:= {x[0.2]}

In:= temp[t_] = x[t] /. sol; temp[0.2]
Out:= {0.00754592}
```

Change the variables in NDSolve may solve this, as

```
NDSolve[eq,{x,v,z},{~}]
```

then the solution can be evaluated at some point directly

```
In:= x[0.2]/.sol
Out:= {0.00754592}
```

But still, I don't know why this could happen that when setdelayed to it, it will not work.

---

Comment: Your definition of `poincare` has one argument and your example uses two arguments.  Something is wrong or missing in the code you posted.

Comment: yes and thank you, the "1" in `poincare[sol,1]` was a misstype!

Comment: @SuGrape This post is not complete.  Could you show one working example of you code to understand your problem?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I posted all the codes, it is based on this [article](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.168743)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually nontrivial: it has to do with how Mathematica manages scope after substituting in values that match a pattern (as in applying `:=`).

By inspecting `poincare[sol, 1] // TracePrint`, we see that after substitution, Mathematica actually uses an expression of the following form:

```
Module[{T$=2 \[Pi],xsol$,vsol$},
 xsol$[t$_] = x[t$] /. {{x[t]->InterpolatingFunction[<<*>>][t], v[t]->InterpolatingFunction[<<*>>][t], z[t]->InterpolatingFunction[<<*>>][t]}};
 vsol$[t$_] = v[t$] /. {{x[t]->InterpolatingFunction[<<*>>][t], v[t]->InterpolatingFunction[<<*>>][t], z[t]->InterpolatingFunction[<<*>>][t]}};
(Evaluate[Join[xsol$[#1],vsol$[#1]]] &) /@ Range[800 T$,1000 T$,T$]]
```

Mathematica has tried to append `$` to the symbol names in an attempt to avoid the very coincidence that you were counting on!

The easiest solution for your case is to extract the `InterpolatingFunction`s directly as the `Head` of `InterpolatingFunction[<<*>>][t]`, and set those to `xsol` and `vsol` after composing with `List` (to recover the singleton list structure).

(I'm also not sure why you have `Evaluate` there, so I took it out, and it seems to work.)

```
poincare[timeseries_, w_] := 
 Module[{T = 2 \[Pi]/w, xsol, vsol}, 
  xsol = List@*Head[First[x[t] /. timeseries]]; 
  vsol = List@*Head[First[v[t] /. timeseries]];
  (Join[xsol[#], vsol[#]]) & /@ Range[800*T, 1000*T, T]]
```

(There are other more in-depth ways to avoid those scoping conflicts, but given that this is not essential to what you're doing, I think it makes more sense to just go directly for what you want! But let me know if you're interested!)

Comment: thank you sooo much!!!  It took me a while to understand, and yes I am interested, it would be very generous of you to show me more references.